# Android : Not able to save Spinner data with SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, spinner

I tried every possible way to load saved spinner data, but it failed. I tried saving `label`(TextView) to `SharedPreferences` and `mySpinner.getSelection` in load preferences, didn't work. This is my Custom Spinner, any ideas how to get it done?

```
 public class AndroidCustomSpinner extends Activity {

    String[] DayOfWeek = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", 
        "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        mySpinner.setAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(AndroidCustomSpinner.this, R.layout.row, DayOfWeek)); 
    }

    public class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

        public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                String[] objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

        @Override
        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
        }

        public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
            View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
            TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.weekofday);
            label.setText(DayOfWeek[position]);

            ImageView icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.icon);

            if (DayOfWeek[position]=="Sunday"){
            icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
            }
            else{
                icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.icongray);
            }

            return row;
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: you wany to store selected item in shared pref?

Comment: Please update your question, and share the exception you get, do we can be more help.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
String value;//Globally declared

    mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
            String value = mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        }
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
```

and once you get the value you can store the value in shared preferences

For storing value in shared preference

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 editor.putString("selected", value );
 editor.commit();
```

for retrieving value from shared preferences

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE); 
String restoredText = prefs.getString("text", null);
if (restoredText != null) {
  String name = prefs.getString("selected", "No selection");

}
```

Comment: What do i write to load preference?

Comment: Thnx, but i need to retrieve the spinner data & i used `mySpinner.getSelection(prefs.getString("selected" ""));` it returns error.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save text in SharedPreferences you can do this code:

```
        SharedPreferences Text;

       public static String filename = "Text";


    Text = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);
    Editor editor = Text.edit;
     editor.putString("name",TextView.getText().toString());
       editor.commit();
```

And then if you want to load this text after restart your app:

```
       Text = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);
       String textname = Text.getString("name", "this is default value if something goes wrong");
```

Comment: I am able to save `TextView` data but i'm getting a FC error in giving the textview data to spinner i.e, my custom textview for spinner.

Comment: SO meaby try to save your spinner TextView

Comment: I did that before, when i give the sharedPreference value to Spinner `TextView`, it forces closes.

Comment: It thorws NullPointerException in logCat?